# If I draw 8 parallel lines on a piece of paper, into how many non-overlapping regions will the lines divide the paper?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: Question and Answer Both Give Here]

I tried to do this sum by visualizing myself drawing 8 parallel lines of a paper. I can't visualize how many non overlapping region will form. And I don't know whether I should consider the edges of the paper as parallel lines or not.

Please Explain like you're teaching a kid. (Started Maths From Scratch!)
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9

Comment: note: 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, ..., 8-9.

Comment: Didn't expect answers within a minute! Understood! Thanks Nomial Animal and Farruhota for answering. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you draw $1$ line then you create $2$ regions.

Every new parallel line will split up an existing region in $2$ regions, so will make the total number of regions increase with $1$.

Comment: Thank You. I've understood and could visualize it

Answer (score 1):

The base case is an empty sheet: *before* you draw any line, you have $1$ region.

Then, every new line, not crossing or overlapping another lines, divides a region in which it is drawn into two, hence increasing the total number of regions by $1$. Eventually, after drawing $n$ lines you have $1+n$ regions.